# Remove specific match from a string

Tags: php

I want to remove a particular match of characters from a string.

For example i have strings;

```
topics-p10-new-model-cars
topics-p20-new-model-cars
topics-p30-new-model-cars
topics-p40-new-model-cars
```

Then i need the results as,

```
topics-new-model-cars
topics-new-model-cars
topics-new-model-cars
topics-new-model-cars
```

That means  i want to remove `p10-,p20-,etc..`
.Those are the page numbers. It may be any number..

How can i do this..? Thanks in advance

Comment: `preg_replace('/\-p\d+\-/', '-', $string)`

Comment: It's very easy, you need to use regex. $slug = preg_replace('@\-p[0-9]{1,3}@', '', $slug);

Comment: @MarkBaker, why do you remove the preceding `-` and then add it back in the replace, rather replace the string with `''` without removing the preceding `-`

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved`!

Comment: @zzlalani - safety - in case there are any actual topics that contain a 'p' followed by digits combination

Comment: Get the answer and a -5...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\-p\d+/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Your previous actually worked. Why did you delete it?

Comment: Coz some stupid people gave me 2x -1

Comment: Coz you copied comment and add it as a answer and waited for ++;

Comment: @PAM: you think, I dont know how to write regular expressions??

Comment: Get the answer and a -5...:)

Comment: It's not the thing - look at the top - this question needs at most comment.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm assuming that the string format does not change (I mean this [topics-p10-new-model-cars]). If my assumption is right.
Then you can do this

```
if (textBox1.Text.Contains("-p10-"))
        {
            //topics-p10-new-model-cars
            String[] splited = textBox1.Text.Split(new char[] {'-'});
            String rString = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}",     
            splited[0],splited[2],splited[3],splited[4]);
            MessageBox.Show(rString);
        }

 //OR This method
        if (textBox1.Text.Contains("-p10-"))
        {
            String result = textBox1.Text.Replace("p10-", "");
            MessageBox.Show(result);
        }
```

Comment: And PHP tag means mothing??

Comment: `If my assumption is right` no Ahmed your assumption is not right here..

Answer (score 0):

With 'preg-replace'::

For, example:

```
<?
echo preg_replace('/p[0-9]+\-/', '', 'topics-p10-new-model-cars');
?>
```

Follow this link:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: I think this will leave the string like `topics--new-model-cars`

Comment: Yes, so answer is wrong.

Comment: OK, re-edited it. added the '\-' (no need to add backslashes).